# DefaultValue in input by type=range

Tags: reactjs

I have an Input by `type=range` that the value of `min` , `max` and `defaultvalue` would be set by  `{this.renderMinTotal()}` and `{this.renderMaxTotal()}` and as you can see the value of `defaultvalue` is the output of `{this.renderMaxTotal()}` but the thumb of input looks that the value of `defaultvalue` is  `{this.renderMinTotal()}` while the value of `defaultvalue` is `{this.renderMaxTotal()}` and in `inspector` the values of   `min` , `max` and `defaultvalue` are correct. 
The output of input in `inspector`:

```
<input type="range" min="17386000" max="178124000" step="1000" class="multirange" value="178124000">
```

It must be like this:
=============[]
while it looks like this:
[]=============

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      library: null,
      perPage: 20,
      currentPage: 1,
      maxPage: null
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/json.bc", {
      method: "get"
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(text => {
        let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'));
        this.setState(
          state => ({
            ...state,
            data: Maindata
          }),
          () => {
            this.reorganiseLibrary();
          }
        );
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const { perPage, data } = this.state;
    let library = data;
    library = _.chunk(library, perPage);
    this.setState({
      library,
      currentPage: 1,
      maxPage: library.length === 0 ? 1 : library.length
    });
  };

  // Previous Page
  previousPage = event => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1
    });
  };

  // Next Page
  nextPage = event => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1
    });
  };

  // handle per page
  handlePerPage = evt =>
    this.setState(
      {
        perPage: evt.target.value
      },
      () => this.reorganiseLibrary()
    );

  // handle render of library
  renderLibrary = () => {
    const { library, currentPage } = this.state;

    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
      return <div className="nodata">NoResult</div>;
    }

    return library[currentPage - 1]
      .sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total)
      .map((item, i) => (
        <div className="item">
          <span>{item._id.value} </span>
        </div>
      ));
  };

  renderMinTotal = () => {
    const { library } = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
      return "";
    }
    return library.reduce((acc, lib) => {
      const libMin = Math.min(...lib.map(item => item.totalCom));
      return acc === undefined ? libMin : libMin < acc ? libMin : acc;
    }, undefined);
  };

  renderMaxTotal = () => {
    const { library } = this.state;

    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
      return "";
    }
    return library.reduce((acc, lib) => {
      const libMax = Math.max(...lib.map(item => item.totalCom));
      return libMax > acc ? libMax : acc;
    }, 0);
  };

  render() {
    const { library, currentPage, perPage, maxPage } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="range"
            min={this.renderMinTotal()}
            max={this.renderMaxTotal()}
            defaultValue={this.renderMaxTotal()}
            step="1000"
            className="multirange"
          />
        </div>
        {this.renderLibrary()}
        <ul id="page-numbers">
          <li className="nexprevPage">
            {currentPage !== 1 && (
              <button onClick={this.previousPage}>
                <span className="fa-backward" />
              </button>
            )}
          </li>
          <li className="controlsPage active">{this.state.currentPage}</li>
          <li className="restControls">...</li>
          <li className="controlsPage">{this.state.maxPage}</li>
          <li className="nexprevPage">
            {currentPage < maxPage && (
              <button onClick={this.nextPage}>
                <span className="fa-forward" />
              </button>
            )}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

Edited Code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      library: null,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/json.bc", {
      method: "get"
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(text => {
        let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'));
        this.setState(
          state => ({
            ...state,
            data: Maindata
          }),
          () => {
            this.reorganiseLibrary();
          }
        );
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    let library = data;
    library = _.chunk(library);
    this.setState({
      library,

    });
  };

  // handle per page
  handlePerPage = evt =>
    this.setState(
      {
        perPage: evt.target.value
      },
      () => this.reorganiseLibrary()
    );

  renderMinTotal = () => {
    const { library } = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
      return "";
    }
    return library.reduce((acc, lib) => {
      const libMin = Math.min(...lib.map(item => item.totalCom));
      return acc === undefined ? libMin : libMin < acc ? libMin : acc;
    }, undefined);
  };

  renderMaxTotal = () => {
    const { library } = this.state;

    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
      return "";
    }
    return library.reduce((acc, lib) => {
      const libMax = Math.max(...lib.map(item => item.totalCom));
      return libMax > acc ? libMax : acc;
    }, 0);
  };

  render() {
    const { library } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="range"
            min={this.renderMinTotal()}
            max={this.renderMaxTotal()}
            defaultValue={this.renderMaxTotal()}
            step="1000"
            className="multirange"
          />
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

Comment: It would be helpful, if you remove all code that is not related to your problem!

Comment: The defaultValue will not be updated after the initial rendering. Might this be your problem?

Comment: Hi @wiesson.I removed all code that is not related to my problem In Edited Code.

Comment: Yes.You right. I did something like this to see what happend:`<input type="range" min={this.renderMinTotal() ||'0'} max={this.renderMaxTotal() ||'10000'}  defaultValue={this.renderMaxTotal()||'10000'} step="1000"
                        onChange={this.handleFilterTotal} className="multirange " />`

Comment: Before the value of `min` ,`max` ,` defaultValue` filled by `this.renderMinTotal()` and `this.renderMaxTotal()` the thumb of input looks correct but when the values updated by `this.renderMaxTotal()` and `this.renderMinTotal()` and I can see that they are updated but I do not know why it looks that  defaultValue will not be updated.

Comment: defaultValue won't be updated, it is only being set on the initial rendering. Just for testing purposes, use `value` instead of `defaultValue` (you won't be able to update the slider though, because onChange handler is missing)

Comment: @wiesson I used `value` instead of `defaultValue` and it was updated, but the handlers of input won't change,although I have 'onChange' function.Could you please show me what should I write in  'onChange' function?